# What do 风、雅、颂 refer to in 《诗经》

Tags: meaning

《诗经》共有风、雅、颂三个部分，

Are they just chapter titles? Do they have more significance?

Comment: It should be *风*、雅、颂.  "诗经根据乐调的不同分为风、雅、颂三类"

Comment: In short,《诗经》is categorized by 乐调, including 风、雅、颂.

Answer (score 1):

風 is general mood (風氣), or social custom (風俗).

in ancient times, there're regional differences between vassal states (諸侯國); after confucius's editing, fifteen "lessons from the state" (國風) were preserved. each groups of poems from the vassal state, shown that particular state's social custom.

雅 is odes of the kingdom (周朝), where the ruler were.

頌 is odes for the purpose of praising in the ancestral temple (宗廟).

the contents, styles of these three groups of poems / odes are significantly different.

Comment: I bought a copy with the original text on the left and Modern Chinese on the right. The Modern Chinese is always much longer!

Comment: @Pedroski, I believe ancient Chinese should be (at least one of) the most concise language in the world!

Answer (score 0):

《诗经》根据乐调不同分为风雅颂三类。
“The Book of Song” divided into three categories according to music.

1.风 - different areas of music.

1.雅 - the music of the Zhou Dynasty rayons.

1.颂 - the Confucian ritual dance song.